# Docker: Mount NFS folders on host or configure them in volumes?

Tags: docker, nfs

I already have a NFS server working, reachable from my Docker hosts. I can connect to my shares using volumes and use them to share data between containers in different hosts.

I have two options to mount this NFS shares in my docker hosts. Both work, but **I'd like to know which is better and why**:

1. **Mount every share on the host boot somewhere**, i.e. `/mnt/nfs/my-share` and then link them using a volume defined as:

```
    ...
        volumes:
          my_nfs_volume:
            driver: local
            driver_opts:
              type: none
              o: bind
              device: /mnt/nfs/my-share
    ...
```

2. **Don't mount any share on the host**. Instead, configure volumes using the nfs type:

```
   ...
   volumes:
      my_nfs_volume:
        driver: local
        driver_opts:
          type: nfs
          o: "addr=my-nfs-server,rw"
          device: ":/nfsshare/my-share"
   ...
```

I'd prefer the second option, 'cause I know what NFS share is using my volume without having to go to see what mount points I have on each host. I can also mount different shares with different permissions or options. Finally, I can move my services between hosts and the only condition is that the destination host is allowed to use the NFS share.

On the other hand, the first option is simpler to debug if we have any NFS issues, 'cause if any nfs-share is lost, Docker won't be very explicit about it.

What do you think?

Comment: For which purpose you're using NFS? For logs?

Comment: Nope. To store container data, files, etc...